# Facebook Javascript API default picture bad url

Tags: facebook-javascript-sdk

Running the Javascript Facebook API it shows a bad url on the default profile picture

```
<fb:profile-pic uid="loggedinuser" linked="true" size="thumb" facebook-logo="false"></fb:profile-pic>
```

This is the init script.

```
<script src="//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js"></script>
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
    FB.init({
        appId: '000000000000000000',
        status: true, 
        cookie: true, 
        xfbml: true
    });    

    // Event: login process
    function loginUser() {
    }                   
</script>
```

Is an annoying issue, the default picture has a bad URL 
http://static.ak.fbcdn.netrsrc.php/v1/yi/r/odA9sNLrE86.jpg

...which is missing one slash: **static.ak.fbcdn.net/rsrc...**

How could be that possible? Facebook release bug?

Comment: Does this occur for all users, or just one?

Comment: well, everyone if not logged. Could you check at http://icloset.frutafrescavirtual.com ?